# Why I get error on string concatination?

Tags: string, nodemcu

exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char [5]' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'

```
  String message = "Page not found\n\n";
  message += "URI: " + HTTP.uri() + "\n";
  message += "Method: " + (HTTP.method() == HTTP_GET)? "GET": "POST" + "\n";
  message += "Arguments: " + HTTP.args() + "\n";
```

Comment: which line is it having problems with?

Comment: try enclosing the ternary operator in brackets `((HTTP.method() == HTTP_GET)? "GET": "POST")`

Answer (score 2):

The operators of the class String apply only for an instance of String. In your expression you concatenate two c-strings "POST" + "\n"

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to just move the (const char *)s around a little:

This should compile

```
  String message = "Page not found\n\n";
  message += "URI: " + HTTP.uri() + "\n";
  message += "Method: " + (HTTP.method() == HTTP_GET)? "GET\n": "POST\n";
  message += "Arguments: " + HTTP.args();
  message += "\n";
```